# Bluetooth Low Energy on different platforms

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to establish a bluetooth low energy link between a custom pcb and a mobile device. The application requires a tablet device and a BLE link that operates as fast as possible.

Since the BLE Speed is main defined by the allowed number of packages per connection interval and the minimal connection interval I'm trying to find a tablet with those capabilitys.

I have been searching a lot and just found the following information:

- IOS device are stuck with a minimal connection interval of 30ms
- Android devices are technically able to deliver 6 packets each 7.5ms, but usually it wont settle for anything below 20ms.

I find it very hard to get solid information on that topic. I found nothing about Windows Tablets and Tizen Tablets.

Does anyone have information about that topic?

Comment: Same question for Windows asked here : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/05c00c02-4a14-4d09-982f-51fddcda4b8c/minimum-connection-interval-in-bluetooth-low-energy-ble-communication?forum=wdk

Answer (score 2):

You see, the standard Android bluetooth code is (with sometimes small adjustments by each manufacturers) the same on every device and the bluetooth controllers available on the market tend to only send 3-6 packets each connection event if the min/max connection event length is set to 0, which it is by default in Android's code.

Is it possible for you to work with AOSP, i.e. modify the Android source code? If so you could change the HCI call where a connection is created or connection parameters are updated. Change the min/max connection event length (Minimum_CE_Length and Maximum_CE_Length) to some large value and you will then be able to write many many packets in one connection event regardless of connection interval.

The relevant places in the code are https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/bt/+/d35bb40dd563e7f37df0a2fa9c0f61d0958b9601/stack/l2cap/l2c_ble.c#945 and https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/bt/+/488005b16bd2552ce7e5f9c1e1b3d4072397fc26/stack/btm/btm_ble_bgconn.cc#394.

Comment: Hey,
it is a good idea I already considered, but since this is supposed to be a platform that will be used and improved by other people than me, I wanted to find a solution that will work "out of the box". The hardware on the phone can most surely handle the desired parameters, android just does not have any API to access those settings. This is why I want to find out if other platforms offer this access or have "better" default settings regarding the connection properties. Thanks for the good Answer though :-)

Comment: I have never seen other solutions that provide the option to set the connection event length. I guess it might be because nobody of the bluetooth host side developers of the platforms knows what it does or doesn't see the benefits in having a larger value. You'll probably have to use some custom solution for this. If you want to go for Android you nevertheless should be able to use at least 12 ms connection interval.